# If statements not initialising JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code for a simple HTML form with JavaScript Validation. I simply want to return an error message if the fields are blank.

At the moment the page just goes straight to the success.html page without initialising the javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ok so I've made some changes and its still not working. Here is the edited code:

```
function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";
if (document.ExamEntry.name.value==="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.Name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}


if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value==="") {
msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
document.ExamEntry.Subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if(msg===""){
return result;
}else{
alert(msg) 
return result;
```

Thanks for all the contributions

Comment: Java and JavaScript is not the same thing.

Comment: And I think you're missing an else statement there as well!

Comment: Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/x2RhT/1/)** what you are looking for..?

Comment: @adeneo Sure they are. Just like ham and hamsters are the same.

Comment: Learn JavaScript. Press F12 in Chrome, go `console` tab and watch where your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The curly parentheses surrounding the logic following the below `if` statement are invalid

```
if (msg !== "") {
    return result;
} {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
}
```

Simply, you should write:

```
if (msg !== "") {
    return result;
}

alert(msg);
return result;
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe OP wanted `} else {` instead of the `} {`

Comment: Do you really need an if statement, they both return the same thing

Comment: There's no need for the `else`, as the `if` statement's logic returns from the function.

Comment: why to alert when `msg === ""`?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, but that logic is at the discretion of the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Am I reading this wrong or are your `if` statement logic backwards?

```
        if (document.ExamEntry.name.value !== "") {
            msg += "You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
            result = false;
        }


        if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value !== "") {
            msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
            result = false;
        }
```

`result` by default is true.  If you fail to enter a value for either fields, then !== "" will be false (because it does equal the empty string) and therefore `result` will be left `true`, which enables form submission.

Try:

```
        if (document.ExamEntry.name.value === "") {
            msg += "You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
            result = false;
        }


        if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value === "") {
            msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
            result = false;
        }
```

Also, as others pointed out, you are missing an else statement:

```
        if (msg !== "") {
            return result;
        } else {
            alert(msg)
            return result;
        }
```

And finally, you mentioned this is Java.  This is JavaScript.  And no, JavaScript is not just a smaller version of Java.  It is a very different language.

Comment: `if (msg !== "") alert(msg); return result;` (1) Why to show msg when msg is emtpy? (2) Why not a single return path?

Comment: Good point.  That was copied from the OP's code, which now, apparently, has been changed dramatically, which invalidates pretty much every answer and comment.

Comment: Humph :( What a waste of time! Am sorry, mate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing with non-empty string while the comparision should have been for an empty string i.e.,if (document.ExamEntry.name.value !== "") { should be changed to if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {

This implies to check for a a non empty string in the text box and redirect to the appropriate page (success page).

Also move the alert(msg) to the if (msg !== "") block. I think you would want to alert the user in case of empty text box.